# C++ system() could not open .txt file when the path have space

Tags: system

I have the txt file in e:/a b
In system() function could not accept the space 
So what to do
My c++ code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    system("start e:/a b/test.txt");
}
```

Comment: Dude it does't open the txt file it opens cmd

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to emulate what you would do on the command line. For instance:

```
system("start \"e:/a b/test.txt\"");
```

As an aside, generally one uses a .bat extension for batch files. Not sure how picky start is on the extension, but it helps for understandability.

Comment: Dude it does not open txt file it opens cmd

Answer (score 0):

I usually make the start upper case like START and i used it like `system("START www.gmail.com");` or you could use 
`system("START *URL or EXE-FILE*");` another way to open it is:

```
CString str = "http://www.wikipedia.org/";
            CString action = "open";
            ShellExecute(NULL, action, str, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
            getchar();
```